# How to find elements that match a specific pattern in a 2d list

Tags: python, optimization, pattern-matching

I would like to find an efficient way to retrieve all the elements in an array that match a specific pattern.

For example, considering that I have:

- an array `M` composed of sub-arrays of different sizes:

  ```
    M = [[0, 1],
         [3, 2, 4],
         [3, 8],
         [9],
         [0, 2],
         [3, 1],
         [0, 3],
         [2, 4],
         [3, 7]]
  ```
- A pattern of subarrays. For example, `[[a, b], [a, c], [a, d]]` matches `[[0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3]]`.

**How can I return all the elements of `M` that correspond to the pattern?**

So far I have been using `for` loops to find matching elements but this naive approach turns out to be very costly when the pattern has more than 2 sub-arrays.

Example:

```
M = [[0, 1], [3, 2, 4], [3, 8], [9], [0, 2], [3, 1], [0, 3], [2, 4], [3, 7]]

# pattern with 3 sub-arrays -> [[a, b], [a, c], [a, d]]

for i, arr1 in enumerate(M):
    for j, arr2 in enumerate(M):
        for k, arr3 in enumerate(M):
            if i != j != k:
                if len(arr1) == len(arr2) == len(arr3) == 2:
                    a1, a2, a3 = arr1[0], arr2[0], arr3[0]
                    b, c, d = arr1[1], arr2[1], arr3[1]
                    if a1 == a2 == a3 and b < c < d:
                        print arr1, arr2, arr3
```

Output:

```
[0,1], [0,2], [0,3]
[3,1], [3,7], [3,8]
```

Since each sub-array accounts for an additional nested loop, the time complexity of this method (`O(n^k)` where `k` is the number of sub-arrays), becomes an issue.

Is it possible to speed up this process? If so, how?

Comment: This has almost nothing to do with numpy. Numpy does not allow ragged arrays.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are doing with the pattern. What happens if you run into a subarray with one element?

Comment: It is filtered out with ‘if len(arr) == 2’. How about making the sub-arrays the same size, filling them with NaN for example. The conditional statements with < > == should still work.

Comment: If you make a non-ragged array, actually use numpy, and vectorize properly, you will see an enormous speed increase

Comment: How is `[3, 1], [3, 7], [3, 8]` a match?

Comment: I don’t know how to do this, hence the question.

Comment: I can show you that part. I just want to make sure I understand what you're actually doing.

Comment: OK. I just got it. The "pattern" is not really a fixed pattern. It's basically exactly your condition. But since you allow the elements to be rearranged, `b < c < d` is really just `b != c != d` for some ordering of `b, c, d`. Can we agree on that?

Comment: OK. Solution coming momentarily.

Comment: Because 1<7<8 (b<c<d) and same value (3) in ‘a’ position. Comparison occurs between items with similar index (y1, y2, y3) not between xs and ys

Comment: I've removed the `numpy` tag. There's really no reason to use numpy here. Numpy's set operation, `np.unique`, is actually more complex than `set` since it uses sorting rather than a hash-table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, before jumping into numpy, let's take a look at your conditions. You require the sub-arrays to have only two elements. So let's pre-filter your array:

```
M = [m for m in M if len(m) == 2]
```

Now you are checking `a1 == a2 == a3 and b < c < d`, but each possible permutation of `b`, `c`, `d` shows up in the sequence. So really, if you find *any* `b != c != d` for a given `a`, you can rearrange it to the right order, knowing that that order will show up eventually.

A very simple way to handle this is therefore to construct a dictionary mapping `a` to all possible options for `b`, `c`, `d`, filter them for a minimum of the number of "subarrays" you want, sort them, and compute all the possible combinations:

```
# set removed duplicates automatically
options = collections.defaultdict(set)

for a, b in (m for m in M if len(m) == 2):  # Use a generator to filter on-the-fly
    options[a].add(b)

for a, bcd in options.items():
    # sort (combinations automatically filters too-short bins)
    for b, c, d in itertools.combinations(sorted(bcd), 3):
        print(f'[{a}, {b}], [{a}, {c}], [{a}, {d}]')
```

This solution is likely algorithmically optimal. It makes a single pass over the initial list to identify potential patterns, and then performs exactly one iteration per pattern. The only thing that is potentially missing here is that duplicates are eliminated entirely. You can handle duplicates by using `collections.Counter` instead of `set`.

Comment: You answer addresses this pattern specifically but fails to provide a general approach to the problem (what if the pattern is [[1,2,3] [4,5,6], [1,4]] or just [[1, 2, 3]] ?). My question is most probably not well formulated or incomplete at best. I am accepting  this answer and will try to ask a better, clearer and well documented question later. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @solub. Feel free to ping me if you come up with a more general formulation of the pattern. This was an interesting problem. As you noticed, I couldn't write a more general solution without dictating your intentions for you.